# WHEN MATCHED clause fails if there's a NULL in the ON columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, null, merge

I'm using a query with merge that works fine if all columns in the ON clause have a value but `WHEN MATCHED` omits if there's a NULL mark in one of the columns:

```
MERGE PEPS AS peps
USING (Lots of Cols..
       FROM PEPS_temp) 
AS temp (Lots of Cols..) 
ON peps.[Name] = temp.[Name] AND 
   peps.[LastName] = temp.[LastName] AND 
   peps.[TypeEntity] = temp.[TypeEntity] AND
   peps.[Source] = temp.[Source]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET peps.[Category] = temp.[Category] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Lots of Cols..) VALUES (temp.[Col], temp.[Col], temp[Col]....)
```

Case: I have target table that I update manually first its Category column so I set `Category='EX BLOCKED'` the source table is the updated list so the clause `WHEN MATCHED` is supposed to update the `Category` column to `'BLOCKED'` if it exists in the source table, if not `WHEN NOT MATCHED` inserts the new rows that do not exist.

Query runs successfully and when checking the lists I detect duplicates:

```
;WITH Duplicados
     AS (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY Name, LastName, TypeEntity, Source ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RowNum, Name, LastName, TypeEntity, Source
         FROM [PEPS])
SELECT * FROM Duplicados
WHERE  RowNum > 1 AND Source='OFAC SDN';
```

All the duplicate rows contain NULL marks in at least one of the columns of the `ON` clause.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Well it is related but it wouldn't have solved my problem

Comment: Knowing NULL value comparison rules in an SQL database would help you solve the problem.

Comment: Note: if the answer resolved your problem, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate for MATCH doesn't fail, it behaves exactly like it is supposed to. NULL is not a value, NULL is a state that indicates there is no value. 
Therefore, any predicate with any comparison to NULL will resolve to 'UNKNOWN' and not to 'TRUE', causing the row to be considered as a non-match.
To deal with that, you will need to decide on the logic and how you would like to evaluate the rows in case you have NULLs. 
For example, if It is only for last name, and you want to consider it a match, you may solve it by extending the predicate to handle the NULL:

```
MERGE PEPS AS peps
USING (Lots of Cols..
       FROM PEPS_temp) 
AS temp (Lots of Cols..) 
ON peps.[Name] = temp.[Name] AND 
   (peps.[LastName] = temp.[LastName] OR peps.LastName IS NULL) AND 
   peps.[TypeEntity] = temp.[TypeEntity] AND
   peps.[Source] = temp.[Source]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET peps.[Category] = temp.[Category] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Lots of Cols..) VALUES (temp.[Col], temp.[Col], temp[Col]....)
```

Comment: "any comparison to NULL will resolve to 'UNKNOWN' and not to 'TRUE'" oh my god this is so logical why I didn't think like this it works now thanks this also applies in a LEFT JOIN query that I used to check already existing rows from target and source

Comment: weeel, I'd say it certainly behaves like that, but claims on that being logical and valid -- I wouldn't be that confident. Zero equals zero, empty set equals empty set. EG CHAR is one item set, containing one element from known superset, null being empty set, no character. Empty set == empty set, null==null should be the normal behavior. If someone wants exceptional comparing apples to oranges which should result in N/A result, he should be objected to extra hassle to get valid result.

Comment: @MartinMucha - can you explain why you think that null is the same thing as an empty set? Hint: it’s not…

Comment: ok, let me rephrase then. The actual problem is that NULL≠NaN. You definitely can compare 2 pointers to equality. Not set column value is not NaN, neither unset pointer, but unset value. It's 'zero' of non-numeric data type. So oracle is illogically using same keyword for different things. Just like empty string is NULL with NaN, for which any comparison yields false. That's invalid. I'm not objecting to how it works, it might have some benefits, I'm just objecting to claim it's sound and logical. IIUC concept of zero was around for like 5000 years, and this kinda violates it.

Comment: @MartinMucha zero is a valid numeric value. Empty string is a valid string value. NULL is not a value. It’s an indicator for missing information. It can’t be compared, manipulated, or otherwise be compared to a value because it is not a value. It is very logical, because the RDM is based on logic. I recommend that you go back and read some RDM fundamentals. I highly recommend Chris Date’s books.

Comment: @DQLRaptor ... and yet with all that 'logic' in place empty string is represented as NULL, or at least I didnt yet see non-null empty string  varchar. If this is logic, then it is javascript one.